# Configure email IDs in config in Splunk

Tags: splunk

Is there a way to configure the send to emails in a config file and call them in all Splunk alerts instead of defining emails in each and every alert?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Splunk believe alerts should be sent to those who need to see them, not necessarily the same people every time.  Of course, that's not the case everywhere.

There is no config file just for alerts.  Alert info is stored with the associated search in savedsearches.conf.  You should be able to define settings common to all alerts in the `[default]` stanza of savedsearches.conf.